# How {a:{b:2}}+10 be calculated in chrome?

Tags: javascript

I tried:
[image]

and:
[image]

and:
[image]

Cannot figure out why

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Copy and paste it into the question instead. I also recommend you take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Please take a look at this question and ask yourself "Is this a proper question?"

Comment: Lol, don't look at this comment, look at the one above. :)

Comment: `expression.a.b + 10`

Answer (score 1):

There can be a number of ways to do this, You need to access the property on the object before using it for example:

```
({a:{b:2}}).a.b+10 // gives you 12
```

You can also use a variable like :

```
var obj = {a:{b:2}}
    obj.a.b+10 // gives 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do simple arithmetic to a nested object itself.

You have to directly access the keys within the object.

Example:

---

```
let expression = {a:{b:2}};

expression + 10; // "[object Object]10" (Concatenates 10 to object string)

{a:{b:2}} + 10;  // 10 (Object is created but not accessed)

// As supra28 stated
({a:{b:2}}).a.b + 10 // 12 (Dynamically created the object and accessed their keys)

expression.a.b + 10 // 12 (Object keys accessed)
```

---

**Reading Material** : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

> A good tip before asking a question you think you can't answer. Put
>   some kind of toy beside your monitor and ask it your question. 8 out of 10
>   times you will answer your own question.